# How can evaluate the success of my algoritm?

Tags: classification, regression, evaluation-functions

A little bit of context. I have a classification algorithm based on mathematical discriminator and I am not applying any machine learning or AI technique, just moving window and several relative comparisons. This is a **signal segmentation** problem, where **I need to detect three states based on their mathematical properties or morphology**. In addition, I need to perform this with **minimum delay and almost real-time**.

The output of my algorithm is a labelled signal with the different sections of it labelleded depending on those mathematical descriptors. The reference model was labelled by professionals that tagged the data for me and I am in charge of creating an automatic labelling tool for it.

Here you can see on the top the reference model and on the bottom the output of my algorithm.

[image]

My question is, I have defined a measure of success function that compares sample by sample the two signals but it is not very accurate and I want to know what is the state of the art in this type of classification problem.

My "measure of success" function:

```
def measure_of_success(signal_size, result_labels, model_labels):
""" Measure of success function """
incorrect_matching = 0
for index in range(signal_size):
    expected_section = identify_section_from_sample(model_labels, index)
    result_section = identify_section_from_sample(result_labels, index)
    if expected_section != result_section:
        incorrect_matching += 1
matching = (1 - (incorrect_matching / signal_size)) * 100
return matching
```

This function performs a sample-by-sample comparison. My problem is: the labels from the upper picture were set by hand but, I does not matter how accurate the section is determined but just to know that the event has been detected for a considerable time. This is a bit confusing but basically, if I detect the same "b" event and it coincides in time with the majority of the reference model, it should be 100% ok. On the other hand, I feel this measure of success is a bit simplistic and there might be better ways like a confusion matrix or something like that.

What would you suggest me to do in order to evaluate the success of the classification?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to AI stack exchange. I suggest you share your "measure of success function" since this is key to understanding how you are evaluating. If you want to compare to state-of-the-art, you will need to give more information about the problem domain and what you already know about state-of-the-art algorithms (this looks like a signal sequence, so I would guess some kind of RNN or CNN might do well - if it is a sequence please make clear whether prediction needs to happen at the moment of sampling for each record or can be done retrospectively). Use [edit] to add details to the question

Comment: I have added some information in the post! Thanks for pointing that out